# Missing Gnome after Upgrade: Open /dev/fb0: Permission denied

Tags: gnome, startup, gpu-driver, iwlwifi

Please help, I can't work with my new working device, a Thinkpad T470.

1. Ubuntu 17.04 startup stops before Gnome desktop comes up.
2. Last message on screen:

   ```
   /dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, xxx/xxxx files, xxx/xxxx blocks3
   ```
3. Only error message in Xorg.0.log:

   ```
   [ 89.181] (EE) open /dev/fb0: Permission denied
   [ 89.181] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
   [ 89.181] (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
   ```
4. May be the reason: One automatic upgrade of `mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64` (17.0.3-1ubuntu1, 17.0.7-0ubuntu0.17.04.1)
5. One obvious? error in dmsg.log:

   ```
   [ 3.631814] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-26.ucode failed with error -2
   [ 3.631967] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-25.ucode failed with error -2
   [ 3.632286] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-24.ucode failed with error -2
   [ 3.632296] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-23.ucode failed with error -2
   [ 3.635251] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.391740.0 op_mode iwlmvm
   ```

This is my first post since year 2000. May I have luck with you guys, thank you in advance! Kind regards, Jörg from Berlin

Comment: Ok, I just reinstalled Gnome, like in https://www.computersnyou.com/4945/re-install-xorg-xserver-completely-ubuntu/.
I am so happy with Linux and the abillity to repair things.

Answer (score 0):

To work around the permissions issue, you can use a Xorg.wrap config file to pass root rights, using:

```
needs_root_rights=yes
```

See man Xorg.wrap for the details.

Comment: I did that on an Ubuntu 18.04 just now. It still does not aleviate the problem, though that error does not show up any more. We now have the issue that the X server just terminates successfully. In the startup of the GNOME session it says that it cannot find `mktemp`, `ls`, `cat`, `env`. This seems very fishy, though.